# Email validation to display message only if email is entered but it is not a valid email

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, email

I want to display message that email address is not valid only if it is entered email address but it is not valid. If no value is entered, I don't want to display message - I just make input border red.

I tried this but it shows message even when field is empty:

```js
function validateEmail($email) {
  var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;
  return emailReg.test( $email );
}
if($(element).hasClass('email')) {
  if( !validateEmail($('.email'))) {
    $('<span>Please enter a valid email address</span>').insertAfter($(element));
  }
}
```

I also tried with a jQuery validate plugin but in this case it doesn't show error for email at all:

```js
var emails = ['email'];
for(var i=0;i< emails.length;i++) {
  var email = emails[i];
  rules[email] = {};
  rules[email].email  = true;
  rules[email].required  = true;
  msgs[email] = {
    required:'',
    email : "Please enter a valid email address",
  }
}

var validateObj           = {}
validateObj["rules"]      = rules;
validateObj["messages"]   = msgs;
validateObj["onkeyup"]    = function(element) { $(element).valid();};
validateObj["success"] = function(element) {};
validateObj["submitHandler"] = function (form) {
  form.submit();
}
$("#form").validate(validateObj);
```

Comment: I can't test it at the moment, but your jquery validate code looks very odd and non-standard. This is a very common use case, there should be a lot of code samples you can use. Avoid using custom regex for email validation, as it will fail in too many edge cases.

Comment: It's not so custom, I'm using jquery validation plugin, it's just written in this way. I define object rules, messages - it's just syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really feel like I'm helping someone who didn't try to do it by himself...

You can use `($(element).val())` to test if your input is empty.

For this one to work, simply declare a `empty-email` class to color borders

```
if($(element).hasClass('email')) {
    if($(element).val()){
        if(!validateEmail($(element))) {
            $('<span>').text('Please enter a valid email address').insertAfter($(element));
        }
    }else{
        $(element).addClass('empty-email');
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, really, I'm very tired and I didn't think of that :(

Comment: Not a good solution, as it still uses the custom email validation. Custom email validation is very problematic, and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution in my case using jquery validation:

```js
var emails = ['email'];
for(var i=0;i< emails.length;i++) {
  var email = emails[i];
  rules[email] = {};
  rules[email].email  = true;
  rules[email].required  = true;
  msgs[email] = {};
  msgs[email] = {
    required:'',
    email : "Please enter a valid email address",
  }
}

if($(element).hasClass('email')) {

  error.insertAfter($(element));

}

};
```